# What is the meaning of casting an integer number wrapped by curly braces in C language?

Tags: c

Happened to see a usage like this:

```c
uint8_t a = 0x1a;
...
foo(&(uint32_t){ a })
...
```

So I tried below code snippet:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    uint8_t a = 0x1a;
    
    printf("0x%x\n", a);
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    printf("%p\n", &a + 1);
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("0x%x\n", (uint32_t){a});
    printf("%p\n", &(uint32_t){a});
    printf("%p\n", (&(uint32_t){a} + 1));
    printf("===============\n");
    printf("%d\n", (&(uint32_t){a} + 1) == (&(uint32_t){a}));
    printf("%ld\n", (&(uint32_t){a} + 1) - (&(uint32_t){a}));
    
    return 0;
}
```

On M1 MacBook, compiled successfully and ran:

```sh
$ gcc try.c -o try.bin
$
$ ./try.bin
0x1a
0x16bb773ef
0x16bb773f0
===============
0x1a
0x16bb773e4
0x16bb773e4
===============
0
2
```

I got confused with below questions based on the printing:

1. Is `(uint32_t){a}` just a casting for `a`(like `(uint32_t)a`) in C language ?

   - If no, the values are the same
   - If yes, the addresses are different
2. Is `&(uint32_t){a}` and `&(uint32_t){a} + 1` same in this case ?

   - If no, the addresses are printed same
   - If yes, `==` and `-` proved they are different

Comment: It's not casting, it's declaring a _compound literal_, a kind of anonymous array with the same scope as any other variable within the scope it was declared.

Comment: @Lundin: Compound literals do not have scopes because they do not have names.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Storage duration then, the difference only matters to language lawyers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Printing the address of an object is a side effect so I don't see how the compiler could print the same address for two different compound literals even if they aren't otherwise used by the program. Allocating two different objects at the same address (optimization) even though there are side effects present on those object would arguably break the rules of the abstract machine.

Comment: @Lundin: `printf("%p\n", (&(uint32_t){a} + 1));` does not print the address of a compound literal. It prints the address **after** a compound literal. The two `printf` statements create two compound literals. It is entirely possible for the address **after** one compound literal to be the **start** address of a different compound literal, just as `int a, b; printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &a, (void *) (&b+1));` could print the same address twice because `b` happens to be just before `a` in memory.

Comment: @Lundin: Furthermore, I compiled and ran the code exactly as shown and got identical outputs for those two `printf` statements, albeit different from OP’s due to address space layout randomization. The fact that it reproduces proves it is reproducible.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah fair enough, they need not be allocated adjacently. I was confused by gcc actually separating the outputs by 8 bytes (not 4 which would mean the same address), whereas clang gives the same address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per C 2018 6.5.2 and 6.5.2.5, source code of the form `( type-name ) { initializer-list }` is a *compound literal*. “It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list… The value of the compound literal is that of an unnamed object initialized by the initializer list.”

It is an lvalue, and you can take its address and even modify it. If it appears outside of a function, it has static storage duration. Otherwise, it has automatic storage duration associated with its enclosing block.

> Is (uint32_t){a} just a casting for a(like (uint32_t)a) in C language ?

No, `(uint32_t) a` merely converts the value of `a` to the type `uint32_t`. The result is just a value that can be used in expressions. Its address cannot be taken. `(uint32_t) {a}` creates a new object in memory.

> Is `&(uint32_t){a}` and `&(uint32_t){a} + 1` same in this case ?

This code creates two objects. Since they are in the same enclosing block, they have essentially the same lifetime (technically the same ending time, when execution of the block ends, but slightly different starting times, when execution reaches each). Since they exist at the same time, they have different addresses. However, `&(uint32_t){a} + 1` points just beyond its `&(uint32_t){a}`, and that location just beyond it could be the same address where the first `&(uint32_t){a}` starts, so those two `printf` statements could print the same address.

Note that, when printing addresses with `%p`, you should convert the address to `void *`, as in:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &(uint32_t){a});
printf("%p\n", (void *) (&(uint32_t){a} + 1));
```

Comment: It makes sense if you consider the fact that these compound literals, just like local variables, end up on the stack. And on most systems, stack grow downward so the second compound literal is at a lower address then the first. But there are no guarantees about that and enabling optimization may well result in a completely different outcome.

Comment: @koder: Whether a stack is used to implement objects with automatic storage duration is irrelevant. The C standard requires objects to have addresses in its computing model and allows them to be placed with consecutive descending addresses regardless of whether a stack is used or not. This answer does not assert that will occur; it says it “could be.”

Comment: @EricPosppischil: Theoretically the stack is indeed irrelevant. But considering a specific implementation of the theory may help in understanding it.